# Drag move flickers position of window

Tags: winforms, rust, imgui, glium

I'm implementing a Rust alternative to .NET's [DragMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.dragmove?view=netcore-3.1) method however the result causes the application to flicker between two relative positions.

See [screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/ZyGwRkcHDXoC) and [sample project](https://github.com/paulcsiki/drag-move-rs).

Code I'm using to perform the drag move:

```
let mut mouse_down = false;
let mut last_pos: Option<PhysicalPosition<f64>> = None;
event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
Event::WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent::CursorMoved {
            position,
            ..
        },
        ..
    } => {
        let gl_window = display.gl_window();
        let window = gl_window.window();
        if mouse_down {
            if last_pos.is_some() {
                let previous_pos = last_pos.unwrap();
                let delta_x = previous_pos.x - position.x;
                let delta_y = previous_pos.y - position.y;
                window.set_outer_position(PhysicalPosition::new(position.x + delta_x, position.y + delta_y));
            }
            last_pos = Some(position);
        }
    }
    Event::WindowEvent {
        event: WindowEvent::MouseInput{
            state,
            button,
            ..
        },
        ..
    } => {
        mouse_down = button == MouseButton::Left && state == ElementState::Pressed;
        if !mouse_down {
            last_pos = None;
        }
    }
    _ => {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CursorMoved](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html) reports

> (x,y) coords in pixels **relative to the top-left corner of the window**.

When you're later using that position to `set_outer_position`, you are essentially reinterpreting window-relative coordinates as screen-relative.

You should instead apply the offset to the position returned from [outer_position](https://docs.rs/winit/0.22.2/winit/window/struct.Window.html#method.outer_position).

While that fixes the immediate problem, I'm not sure it is enough to account for the window movement. When you're handling the *next* `CursorMoved` event, the coordinates are still window-relative, but the window has since moved. That may produce artifacts all over.

A more robust solution would store the window's position when the drag-move operation starts, and offset that position by the accumulated deltas.